# Regarding sizeof() and allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

Say I had the following code:

```
int main() {

    char *a = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    int b = 0;

    b = (a + 1) - a;

    printf("%d\n", b);  // Why does this equal sizeof(char) ?
}
```

I don't really understand how `b = (a + 1) - a` is equal to `sizeof(char)`. If I changed it from `char*` to say `double*`, it would then be sizeof(double).

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, `a` is larger than `b` can hold. Notwithstanding what is `anypointer + 1 - anypointer`?? `:)` (e.g. `next address - current = sizeof type`)

Comment: " If I changed it from char* to say double*, it would then be sizeof(double)."  - try that and report back

Comment: I tried and I still and getting 1, even after casting a to (double*) so it is `double * a = (double*)malloc(4*sizeof(double))` I am getting 1. Was my professor wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a value to a pointer, the resulting pointer points to a different array element.  In this case `a` points to array index 0, so `a + 1` points to array index 1.

When you then subtract one pointer from another, the result is the difference in the array indexes.  So `b` will always be 1 regardless of the type of the pointer.  Changing `a` to have type `double *` won't change the result.

Comment: Interesting, I tested it for a char originally and I got 1, which I assumed meant it worked for all the other types. Even with a double it is still 1, but my professors answer was the sizeof(type) where type is whatever type 'a' was.

Comment: @JackKelly That would be the case *if* the pointers were caster to `char *`.

Comment: I tried casting a to a double*, so it is `double * a = (double*)malloc(4*sizeof(double))` and I still am getting 1. Shouldn't I be getting sizeof(double)?

Comment: @JackKelly Not there.  Only if you did something like `b = (uintptr_t)(a + 1) - (uintptr_t)a;`

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer pointing to an array of `char`.   `a[0]` is the first element of the array, `a[1]` is the first element of the array.   The distance between `a[0]` and `a[1]` is one char size.

Now `a[0]` is equivalent to `*a`, and `a[1]` is equivalent to `*(a+1)`.

If you change the type of `a` to `double *`, then it becomes a pointer pointing to an array of `double`, applying the above logic, you will get that the distance between `a[0]` and `a[1]` is one double size.

Answer (score 1):

When you have 2 pointers of the same type (ideally, pointing to elements of the same array), subtracting the lower pointer from the higher pointer gives you the *distance* (the number of elements) between them.  This is a key feature of pointer arithmetic.  So, in your example, subtracting `a` from `a+1` gives you a result of 1 because there is 1 element between the two addresses being pointed at (the result is 1 whether you use `char*` or `double*` pointers).

Answer (score 1):

This is simple arithmetic. The expression `(a+1)-a` can be simplified to just `1`. This can be seen easily if you first rewrite it to `(a-a) + 1`. And this is equal to `sizeof (char)` because the size of a `char` is always 1.

(Note that this reasoning may not always apply in pointer arithmetic. `a-a` is `0`, but `a+a` is not valid.)

Comment: Logic is alluring but dangerous. You can write a-a but not a+a . So the parallel with numbers/math is not quite as one may expect. (Not disputing what you are saying)

Comment: Nice!l  The real issue is that a+n is more like a + n*sizeof(a[0]) ie pointer + is v assymetric!